# Django deployment in centos server

Tags: django, ubuntu, centos

I generally deploy django web applications in Ubuntu.

But currently we are using cpanel(not looking for alternatives) which doesnt work in Ubuntu. so want to know if moving to centos for cpanel is worth ?

Because my fear is, if we move to centos server, do we have to face some complex issues(with django deployment) that we might take lot of time(we are good at Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Deploying on centos is essentialy the same. You will probably want to run django in gunicorn and supervisor watching over the process. And nginx for serving static files.

I have done deployment on CentOS aswell as on Ubuntu and I didn't encounter any problems.